# Не могу загрузить пакет из приватного репозитория. Как исправить?

Tags: golang

Есть приватный репозиторий. Я могу склонировать себе данный репозититорий по ssh, но через `go get` / `go install` происходит ошибка:

```
go: unrecognized import path "private.gitlab.ru/repositoryName": https fetch: Get "https://private.gitlab.ru/repositoryName?go-get=1": dial tcp 255.255.255.255:443(левый IP адрес): i/o timeout
```

Пытался устанавливать хост данного репозитория себе в переменные `GONOPROXY` / `GOPRIVATE` / `GONOSUMDB`. Ничего из этого не помогло, ошибка остаётся той же.

Хост пробовал устанавливать в таких форматах `private.gitlab.ru`, `private.gitlab.ru/*`, `private.gitlab.ru/`. Не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если есть доступ по SSH можно использовать такой вариант:

```
git config --global url."git@private.gitlab.ru".insteadOf "https://private.gitlab.ru"
```

Или используя access токен

```
git config --global url."https://${user}:${personal_access_token}@private.gitlab.ru".insteadOf"https://private.gitlab.ru"
```

После этого `go get` / `go install` будут работать с приватными репозиториями.